# maximumSelectionLength not available in react select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

We are migrating to react-select v2 and when previously using the select2 
JS version where  "maximumSelectionLength" was available to control the elements that can be selected in Multi Select.

I could not find the corresponding option here : https://react-select.com/props

Can anyone please guide me about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select2 and react-select are not affiliated with each other and therefore do not have the same APIs available.

In order to replicate the effect of `maximumSelectionLength` in react-select, I would recommend using [controlled props](https://react-select.com/advanced#controlled-props) to check the value against maximum selection size so that you can remove further options from being available once the maximum is reached.

Similar to how this sandbox works https://codesandbox.io/s/x7mv9n0084

Though you will have to adapt it to your multiSelect-maxSize usecase.

Comment: thanks. will control the options to adapt maximumSelectionLength behavior.